# return mysql row if max id is greater than value?

Tags: mysql, max

How do you get mysql to return a row if the max id for two other criteria is greater than the supplied value? The id is the PK.

Along the lines of

```
$value = 7;

SELECT id, msg 
FROM table1 
WHERE col2=$var 
  AND col3=$var2 
  AND ("max id belonging to $var and $var2 on  those columns is > $value");
```

```
id (PK)  |  name   |  age  |  msg
```

I've tried various positions for max(id) and combinations of GROUP BY, but haven't cracked it.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? Maybe we can show other ways also.

Comment: That seems to be two different statements.. Maybe you can evaluate if your max id is greater than value before executing the query?

Comment: I'm keeping the id of the last message retrieved in a session var. When I check in with the server, I only want it to return a row if there is a new row id higher than the one in the session var, where col2=$var AND col3=$var2. The message goes out to multiple recipients, so I can't mark the messsage as 'read'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, msg FROM table1 WHERE col2=$var AND col3=$var2 AND id > $value ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but it gives an 'Invalid use of group function' error.

Comment: Cheers guys - I ended up inserted the data in a different way so that there's only ever one row for each occurrence of col2=$var AND col3=$var2, so no need to find the max id now.